# Is it possible to send a document in docusign api in order?

Tags: docusignapi

We are using docusign api for a while. We have a new requirement to send single document to multiple recipients in order(e.g after first user signed the document successfully then the same signed document should go to seconde user and so on). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the `routingOrder` attribute of the `signer` object. The `signer` object is documented on the [Envelopes:create](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create#definitions) page.